# C++: When I assign the values to a buffer, it doesn't work

Tags: c++, arrays, type-conversion, buffer

Ok, so I have a piece of code. This will insert the header's content into a buffer:

```
buffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(totalSize);
buffer[0] = ((header.sequenceNumber >> 24) & 0xFF);
buffer[1] = ((header.sequenceNumber >> 16) & 0xFF);
buffer[2] = ((header.sequenceNumber >> 8) & 0xFF);
buffer[3] = (header.sequenceNumber & 0xFF);
buffer[4] = ((header.ackNumber >> 24) & 0xFF);
buffer[5] = ((header.ackNumber >> 16) & 0xFF);
buffer[6] = ((header.ackNumber >> 8) & 0xFF);
buffer[7] = (header.ackNumber & 0xFF);
buffer[8] = ((header.connectionId >> 8) & 0xFF);
buffer[9] = (header.connectionId & 0xFF);
buffer[10] = (0 & 0xFF);
unsigned i = (((unsigned)header.ack) << 2) + (((unsigned)header.syn) << 1) + (unsigned)header.fin;
buffer[11] = (i & 0xFF);
```

, and the buffer content is completely wrong. I tried to debug by adding this piece of code:

```
std::cerr << "DEBUG: Values are: " 
    << ((header.sequenceNumber >> 24) & 0xFF) << ", " 
    << ((header.sequenceNumber >> 16) & 0xF) << ", " 
    << ((header.sequenceNumber >> 8) & 0xFF) << ", "
    << (header.sequenceNumber & 0xFF) << ", " 
    << ((header.ackNumber >> 24) & 0xFF) << ", " 
    << ((header.ackNumber >> 16) & 0xFF) << ", "
    << ((header.ackNumber >> 8) & 0xFF) << ", " 
    << (header.ackNumber & 0xFF) << ", " 
    << ((header.connectionId >> 8) & 0xFF) << ", "
    << (header.connectionId & 0xFF) << ", " 
    << (0 & 0xFF) << ", " 
    << (i & 0xFF) << endl;

std::cerr << "DEBUG: Buffer header is: " 
    << buffer[0] << ", " << buffer[1] << ", " << buffer[2] << ", " 
    << buffer[3] << ", " << buffer[4] << ", " << buffer[5] << ", "  
    << buffer[6] << ", " << buffer[7] << ", " << buffer[8] << ", " 
    << buffer[9] << ", " << buffer[10] << ", " << buffer[11] << endl;

std::cerr << "DEBUG: getBuffer ends. The size is " << totalSize 
    << ". The buffer is " << buffer << endl;
```

And this is shown in the console:

```
DEBUG: Values are: 0, 0, 48, 57, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2
DEBUG: Buffer header is: , , 0, 9, , , , , , , ,
DEBUG: getBuffer ends. The size is 12. The buffer is
```

The 12 values are correct. But the 12 elements of the buffer are completely wrong.

Comment: malloc? You are writing C++. Use std::vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon the buffer content is correct, but your way of reporting it to stderr fails.

```
std::cerr << "DEBUG: Buffer header is: " 
          << buffer[0];
```

writes a `uint8_t` to stderr (if `buffer` is of type `uint8_t*`), but that's just a `unsigned char` and thus uses ASCII encoding. To get the correct integer value, use

```
std::cerr << "DEBUG: Buffer header is: " 
          << int(buffer[0]);
```

Comment: Great. I changed it a bit, to (int) buffer[0], and it works.

Comment: @NormalGuy Glad it helped. Btw, `int(buffer[0])` is the C++ style, `(int)buffer[0]` is bad-old C style and not recommended (but you seem to be a C hacker given your usage of `malloc()`).